# Mongoose inserts Number as Int32 or double, how to force to always use double, like the shell does

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

when a field is of type Number, mongoose will insert it as Int32 or double depending on the actual value:

5 -> Int32
5.3 -> double

Effectively the same field has different types depending on the entity inserted.

This is not an issue to read/write from javascript as both are converted to Number. However, if you are simultaneously using a driver from a strong typed language with both types, like C#, this becomes an issue.

Is it possible to configure mongoose to insert the Number always as double, like the mongo shell does?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [mongoose-double](https://github.com/aheckmann/mongoose-double) type for that.